# What is "puhlst"?

Tags: meaning

This sentence appears among the subtitles to a recent Tatort:

> Tauchst nach all den Jahren wieder auf und **puhlst** in der schlimmsten Wunde meines Lebens?

I am unable to find any reference to the word, puhlst/puhlen. Please advise. Is this a typo?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/pulen

Comment: "You show up again after all these years and reopen the worst wound of my life?", something along those lines.

Comment: de: 'puhlst in der schlimmsten Wunde' I would translate 'you stick your finger in my worst wound' ###
puhlen is like sticking your finger in your nose to get something out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word is pulen / du pulst. It's a northern German word. There is no good English equivalent, it basically means to fiddle around / tamper with something using your fingers, often taking something off while doing it. It also means to peel off the paring of fruit or to shell a prawn ("Krabben pulen"). "In der Nase pulen" means to pick one's nose.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/pulen

"In alten Wunden pulen" would be tampering with and potentially opening old wounds, which is used in a figurative sense in the Tatort line.

"Puhlst" is a spelling mistake, and an understandable one. If German spelling was logical, it should probably be "puhlen", but for some reason it stayed "pulen".

Comment: With shrimp it could be "shell", with peas it can be "peel" which actually is the same word (I assume).

Comment: The "h" would be used to indicate a long vowel, but then if the vowel was short there would be a double "l". So there is some logic in the spelling, just not much consistence ;)

Comment: "Krabben pulen" - das erinnert mich an eine Entgleisung Thomas Gottschalks. In https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/zdf-stellt-wetten-dass-ein-schluss-mit-schraegen-wetten.691.de.html?dram:article_id=282225 nach "Krabben" suchen.

Comment: Fiddle around, mess with, poke, stir can all work depending on context. For a wound poke would be a possibility.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica. "Peel" is from Latin and is not cognate with "pulen".

Comment: @fdb Hm, interesting.  Pellis and pilus... maybe not. German has also *pellen* which still seems not related to lat. *pellis*.